# Swift - nil checking an NSCopying function argument

Tags: swift

I'm converting some Obj-C code to Swift and have hit upon a problem. Here's the ObjC code:

```
- (void)collisionBehavior:(UICollisionBehavior *)behavior 
               beganContactForItem:(id<UIDynamicItem>)item 
            withBoundaryIdentifier:(id<NSCopying>)identifier 
                           atPoint:(CGPoint)p {
    NSLog(@"Boundary contact occurred - %@", identifier);
}
```

This is implementing a protocol method from `UICollisionBehaviorDelegate`, and here is the Swift:

```
func collisionBehavior(behavior: UICollisionBehavior,
  beganContactForItem item: UIDynamicItem,
  withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying,
  atPoint p: CGPoint) {

  println("Boundary contact occurred - \(identifier)")
}
```

The above fails with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` if a collision occurs for an object without an identifier. In this case `identifier` has a value of `0x0`, i.e. it is nil.

However, I cannot perform a nil check as follows:

```
if identifier != nil {
  println("Boundary contact occurred - \(boundaryName)")
}
```

Because the `!=` operator is not define for `NSCopying`. Does anyone know how I can check for nil, or is there a 'to string' operation I can perform that doesn't fail when it encounters a nil value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you can use the same workaround that is documented in the 
[Xcode 6.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html) for methods, properties, or initializers for which the return value is incorrectly considered non-nullable:

```
let identOpt : NSCopying? = identifier
if let ident = identOpt {

}
```

Even better you can actually change the methods signature replacing `NSCopying` with `NSCopying?`:

```
func collisionBehavior(behavior: UICollisionBehavior,
  beganContactForItem item: UIDynamicItem,
  withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying?,
  atPoint p: CGPoint) {
  if let unwrapedIdentifier = identifier {
    println("Boundary contact occurred - \(unwrapedIdentifier)")
  } else {
    println("Boundary contact occurred - (unidentified)")
  }
}
```

Comment: @Wayne: The method is defined in a protocol (https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollisionBehaviorDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollisionBehaviorDelegate/collisionBehavior:beganContactForItem:withBoundaryIdentifier:atPoint:), so I think that you cannot just change the prototype. But I did not test it.

Comment: @MartinR - thanks, that worked. But I also found an even better way (I've edited your answer)